# Holding down the Alt key for several seconds makes keyboard behave strangely

Tags: keyboard, alt-tab, keymap, alt

When I hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button on my Keyboard for my than 5 seconds, my keyboard and mouse starts acting very strange. For example, when I try typing, none of the typing keys work. Some buttons do strange things, for example, <kbd>Esc</kbd> causes windows to minimize. When I click in my code editor (Sublime) it leaves a cursor in every spot I click. Lots of other weird behavior happens.

The only way to get out of this *mode* is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> again (this time just for a moment is OK)

Has anyone had a similar experience? Is this unique to my computer, my hardware, etc?

Btw, I have a [Microsoft Comfort Curve 3000 Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004V94F5C), which I'm very happy with.

Comment: Are you using any input manipulation utilities i.e. autohotkey/xpadder?

Comment: @jatuttle0 No I am not

Comment: Does this happen with both left and right alt keys? Have you tried a different keyboard? Same keyboard on a different pc?

Comment: @CodyBugstein I have the same keyboard and the exact same problem. I'm on Windows 10. What are you on? And have you found a way to solve it, yet?

Comment: No I haven't yet

Comment: FYI the Sublime Text cursor behavior is a feature. Clicking while holding Alt lets you add cursors. Pressing Ctrl+D multiple times is similar: first time it selects current word and then adds its following occurrences to selection.

Answer (score 2):

This is a built-in accessibility feature for those who have mobility issues with their hands and/or fingers.

Holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> buttons for 5 seconds or longer locks the key **on**. Users need to go into accessibility features to turn this feature **off**.

This enables people with disabilities to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + any key combinations even if they can only use one finger or have a variety of other impairments.

While the feature is **on**, every key you hit is <kbd>ALT</kbd> & the secondary key you pressed at simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* have to do with "USB selective suspend": a quick search shows people who have ctrl/shift/alt keys "sticking" and problems with keyboard repeat who solved that by modifying a registry value associated with their device.

It is a convoluted process to identify the registry key to edit and disable the feature. You first need the vendor, product and instance IDs from the **device manager** property page of the keyboard:

> An example of all three concatenated:
>
> USB\VID_045E&PID_000E\6&61F43E3&0&2
>
> Open regedit.exe, navigate to:
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SYSTEM\ CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB**
>
> Expand the **USB** folder and open the folder with the name that
>   matches the VID and PID
>
> Find the folder that matches the Instance ID (in the example, it’s
>   6&61F43E3&0&2)
>
> Under the Instance ID key, select **Device Parameters**.
>
> In the details pane, right-click the
>   **EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled** entry and then click Modify.
>
> Change the Value data to 0 and then click OK

The above is summarized from ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usbcoreblog/2013/11/08/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-my-usb-device-doesnt-charge-or-it-disconnects-and-reconnects-frequently/ ) which has pictures and more detail.