# Holding ALT for longer causes it to stick up to 3 seconds after release

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

When I use ALT key, for instance `ALT + TAB` if I press ALT key for 2 seconds then it will act as pressed for additional 2 seconds(up to 3 seconds) as it was pressed. This means that the selected application will not be brought up to focu immediately and also will cause accidental combinations to be selected.

Sticky keys are turned off. Here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/holding-alt-down-makes-it-stick/4ae39e59-93ab-47ca-ac4b-2f2e22378d9d somebody reports the same bug, but no resolution is provided.

I wish my keyboard to stop applying ALT mask as soon as I release the key.

**EDIT:** It happens on all keyboards using both radio receiver or bluetooth, it happens regardless of the application but the most prominent example is using `ALT+TAB` in Windows 11.

Comment: Do you by chance have a Microsoft Keyboard? Like the question here https://superuser.com/q/1075782/368970

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the keyboard ?

Comment: A long Alt press can also be used to toggle some other features. See https://superuser.com/questions/1075782/holding-down-the-alt-key-for-several-seconds-makes-keyboard-behave-strangely , for example

Comment: Have you seen these https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically

Comment: try using a different keyboard, to determine if it's a hardware or a software issue

Comment: Does it happen all the time? On specific applications? Try pressing long ALT here to see if that's hardware problem; https://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html

Comment: @Yoda: You have added a bounty, but have not answered any of the above comments. Please do answer them.

Comment: As @Netan said, could be hardware issues. Maybe the switch requires lubrication or a spring change. This happened to my Windows key as well and the solution is simply changing the switch and the problem is gone. I would recommend this site: https://keyboard-test.space/ as it shows the current key press state.

Comment: Do you have a different keyboard? If you replace and test with that one, does it too have the problem? Have you confirmed all Windows Updates are installed, have you tried resetting any keyboard settings to default, have you checked for firmware updates to BIOS with your computer? Could be a hardware problem so test with a different keyboard while the other is disconnected, and go ahead and reboot too for additional thoroughness. Make sure Windows Updates are not pending install or download too, resolve and update all that, reboot, test with different keyboard, then [edit] to add more detail.

Comment: @Yoda hasn't intervened on this post since June 14, when he received an AI-generated "answer". [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389834/statement-from-so-june-5-2023-moderator-action?cb=1)

Comment: @harrymc what does AI-generated have to do with it? He also didn't answer any of the comment questions since June 1st...

Comment: Have a look at the edit.

Comment: If it happens with all keyboards, do you have any software that may alter how Alt works? AutoHotkey or anything alike.

Comment: @Yoda: Welcome back. Please try it when booting in Safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

As this happens on multiple keyboards and applications, and even in
Windows itself, the problem must be related to software and
not to hardware.
As this is not a feature of Windows, I would guess that it's caused
by some installed third-party product.

To verify this assumption, you could boot in Safe Mode and see
if this fixes the problem. If it is fixed, then this is the proof
that some third-party application is responsible for it.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system boot
or login in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior and rebooting. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

You should start with applications that may relate to facilitate
the handling of the keyboard.